# SignalR (asp.net core) not sending Complex class object

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

SignalR for some reason fails when I try to send an object from client to be represented in a complex class.

The below client-side code works fine...

```
connection.send("ABC", "111", "222", { text: "text" }).then(() => console.log("sent")).catch((r) => console.log(r))
```

...for the below server-side code

```
public async Task ABC(string a, string b, User c)
{
     await Clients.All.SendAsync(RECEIVE, a, b, c);
}

public class User
{
      public string Text { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The below doesn't work....

```
connection.send("ABC", "111", "222", { text: "text", jsonOptions: [] }).then(() => console.log("sent")).catch((r) => console.log(r))
```

...for the below server side code

```
public async Task ABC(string a, string b, Post c)
{
     await Clients.All.SendAsync(RECEIVE, a, b, c);
}

public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required] [StringLength(450, ErrorMessage = "Sender id cannot be more than 450")]
        public string SenderId { get; set; }

        [Required] [StringLength(30, ErrorMessage = "Sender name cannot be more than 30")]
        public string SenderName { get; set; }

        [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "Senderpic length must not be more than 300")]
        public string SenderPic { get; set; }

        public PostLocation PostLocation { get; set; }

        public int? CourseId { get; set; }
        public int ClassId { get; set; }
        public int? ChatId { get; set; }
        public int? LectureId { get; set; }

        [Required] [StringLength(2000, ErrorMessage = "Post text cannot be more than 2000")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public DateTimeOffset TimeStamp { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int Upvotes { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> UpvoteIds { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> DownvoteIds { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> StarredIds { get; set; }

        public PostType Type { get; set; }

        public bool IsReply { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey(nameof(FullRepliedPost))]
        public int? RepliedId { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public MiniPost RepliedPost { get; set; }

        [StringLength(300, ErrorMessage = "ProfilePicturePath length must not be more than 300")]
        public string AttachmentPath { get; set; }

        public AttachmentType AttachmentType { get; set; }

        public int AnsweredPostId { get; set; }
        public Choice CorrectAnswer { get; set; }

        public string JsonOptions { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> Options => (ICollection<string>)
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JsonOptions, typeof(ICollection<string>));

        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> ASelectionIds { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> BSelectionIds { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> CSelectionIds { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> DSelectionIds { get; set; }
        [NotMapped]
        public ICollection<string> ESelectionIds { get; set; }

        #region navigation properties
        [JsonIgnore]
        public Post FullRepliedPost { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<PostVote> PostVotes { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<PostStar> PostStars { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public ICollection<MultiChoice> OptionSelections { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore] [ForeignKey(nameof(RepliedId))]
        public ICollection<Post> Replies { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
```

I use the above Post class as a business object, that's why it has all those attributes. I wonder if that has something to do with the failure. I get the below error in Chrome dev tools

```
[2020-11-07T20:19:42.768Z] Information: Connection disconnected.
```

and when I try to send again, I get an error saying that I can't send messages when signalR is disconnected.

EDIT: I omitted something in the code I pasted here (`jsonOptions: []`), which turned out to be the actual cause of the problem.

Comment: Entity classes are not DTOs. That said, the "Connection disconnected" message is probably unrelated (note that it isn't an Error-level message, only an Info-level message).

Comment: If you have Lazy-Loading enabled then what's likely happening is **SignalR is serializing your entire database** - I hope you can see the problem there...

Comment: @Dai. I also feel it's a serialization problem. I'm going to strip the class down bit by bit until I see what property is causing the error. Or maybe I should just go about it another way. I don't know if it's a better idea to just send the Id of the post and have the receivers fetch the post from the server.

Comment: "Or maybe I should just go about it another way" **you should!** because you should NOT be serializing Entity Classes directly. **You need to define a dedicated DTO type.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the problem was entirely my fault. The `JsonOptions` property in the entity class should be a string, but I was sending an array from the client. Replacing `jsonOptions: []` with `jsonOptions: "[]"` fixed it and it serialized fine.

Regardless, I've decided to just send the Id of the Post object instead of the whole object. I think it's going to be more efficient that way.